# Trouble with Int Theory in Isabelle/HOL

Tags: isabelle

I am working on a proof which I was able to reduce to “of_int i = 0 ==> i = 0”. This seemed like a simple application of the rule “of_int_eq_0_iff” however I was unable to successfully apply this rule.
On further probing I found that I was unable to prove the following lemma

```
lemma of_int_eq_0_imp1: “of_int i = 0 ==> i = 0”
```

by any means whatsoever. That is, unless I declare the lemma within the context ring_char_0. Then the lemma can easily be proved as follows:

```
context ring_char_0 begin
lemma of_int_eq_0_imp1: “of_int i = 0 ==> i = 0”
  using of_int_eq_iff [of i 0] by simp
end
```

But then I cannot apply this lemma outside of this context, which is what my main theorem requires (it resides within a different context).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you can only prove your lemma inside `ring_char_0` should make you suspicious. The reason for this is that the lemma `of_int_eq_0_iff` is defined in the context of `ring_char_0` itself. You can see this by typing e.g.

```
declare [[show_sorts]]
thm of_int_eq_0_iff
> (of_int (?z∷int) = (0∷?'a∷ring_char_0)) = (?z = (0∷int))
```

The reason for this is that in a ring with a characteristic k ≠ 0, this does not hold. In such a ring, `of_int n` will be zero for all multiples n of k, despite n not being 0.

If your original goal reduces to `of_int i = 0 ==> i = 0` then maybe your original goal only holds for rings of characteristic 0, or you need a different proof, one that does not require `of_int i = 0 ==> i = 0`.